# Eliminate Empty lines when present? method used

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a product show page with attributes, but not all are mandatory. So I'm using the `present?` method to determine if the attribute is present, and if it's blank, it doesn't show any field label or input.

This works fine but my problem is it leaves blank lines instead of condensing. So for example the user sees this on the product page:

```
Air conditioning: Window Unit 

Flooring: Carpet
```

Gets created if the user doesn't input anything for basement (notice gap between two lines - if an attributes is blank, I want the gap eliminated and next line presented).

Here's my product/show:

```
<% if @property.air_conditioning.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :air_conditioning %>: 
  <%= @property.air_conditioning %>
<% end %><br />
<% if @property.basement.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :basement %>: 
  <%= @property.basement %>
<% end %><br />
<% if @property.flooring.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :flooring %>: 
  <%= @property.flooring %>
<% end %><br />
```

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your `if` statement closely, you will notice that the `<br/>` tag is *outside* the if-block. So it will insert breaks even if there is no products, leading to the new lines.

So change it to this:

```
<% if @property.air_conditioning.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :air_conditioning %>: 
  <%= @property.air_conditioning %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
<% if @property.basement.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :basement %>: 
  <%= @property.basement %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
<% if @property.flooring.present? %>
  <%= label_tag :flooring %>: 
  <%= @property.flooring %>
  <br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's the tiny mistakes like these that hurt the most.  Thank you! Exactly what I needed.